# unable to run react-native test with jest

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs

jest keeps failing on react-native 0.61.5

https://github.com/mindsgn/OrbytDapp/issues/8

yarn run v1.21.1
$ jest
 FAIL  **tests**/App-test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
ReferenceError: __DEV__ is not defined

  3 |  */
  4 | 
> 5 | import 'react-native';
    | ^
  6 | import React from 'react';
  7 | import App from '../App';
  8 | 

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js:353:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/App-test.js:5:1)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.597s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here... :/